# error when i insert data and select last id

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-insert, executescalar

I want to get `id` after I insert a row of data into a table but I get an error:

> System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.

This is my code

```
SqlCommand cmd_insert = new SqlCommand("insert into ITM_OrderItem (ITM_Code, ITM_Desc, ORCAT_Desc, ORSCT_Desc, ARCBG_Abbrev, ARCSG_Desc, ARCSC_Code, ARCIM_DerivedFeeItem, OPD_Price, IPD_Price, Tou_Price, App_Status, SITES, CSSUSR_RowId, CSSUSR_DepId, CSSUSR_PosId , CDate, MDate) values('"
                       + dt.Rows[i]["EARCIM_Code"].ToString() + "','"
                       + dt.Rows[i]["EARCIM_Desc"].ToString() + "','"
                       + dt.Rows[i]["EORCAT_Desc"].ToString() + "','"
                       + dt.Rows[i]["EARCIC_Desc"].ToString() + "','"
                       + dt.Rows[i]["EARCBG_Abbrev"].ToString() + "','"
                       + dt.Rows[i]["EARCSG_Desc"].ToString() + "','"
                       + dt.Rows[i]["EARCSC_Desc"].ToString() + "','"
                       + dt.Rows[i]["EARCIM_DerivedFeeItem"].ToString() + "','"
                       + dt.Rows[i]["OPD"].ToString() + "','"
                       + dt.Rows[i]["IPD"].ToString() + "','"
                       + dt.Rows[i]["Tourist"].ToString() + "','"
                       + status_app + "','"
                       + usr_site + "','"
                       + usrID + "','"
                       + Dep_RowId + "','"
                       + Pos_RowId + "','"
                       + Cdate + "','"
                       + Cdate + "') select SCOPE_IDENTITY()", conEMR);

// error on this line
insert_RowId = (Int32)cmd_insert.ExecuteScalar();
```

Thank you a lot.

Comment: Remove the quotes (i.e. single) `''` for numeric data types.

Comment: PLEASE look into SQL injection and use parametrized queries instead of text see  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Would you mind showing the schema of your `ITM_OrderItem` table?

Comment: i want to receive id from insert data

Comment: this command is work fine in sql query.

Comment: i convert.toInt32(cmd.excutescalar) it work thank you alot.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if the identity column in your table ITM_OrderItem does not use **int** as data type, What I can guess is that it is a **bigint** data type and if that is the case you should change the line in your code to:

```
insert_RowId = (Int64)cmd_insert.ExecuteScalar();
```

Also make sure that you change the datatype of variable '**insert_RowId**' to **Int64** in your C# code declaration.

Comment: What is the data type of the Identity Column of Your Table **ITM_OrderItem**.

Comment: data type of the Identity Column is int

Comment: [ITM_RowId]            INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,

Comment: In that case the issue is not with line of with the data type in C# code and the casting. I can now bet that the insert statement fails returning a null value for 'select SCOPE_IDENTITY()' and hence you should try generating the T-SQL for the insertion from the code, run the T-SQL in Sql Server Management Studio and Fix Accordingly. It seems as if you are passing character data in the insert statement where numeric data is expected or vice-versa. if you can share the schema of the table I sure will be able to help you on this.

Comment: i try to dbug porcess and copy cmd to write on sql query it's work fine.